# JavaScript is not working when using UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page that has the JavaScript code.
In a WebForm I use this JavaScript code successfully.
But when I use `UpdatePanel`, then this code is not working.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>              
      //code is here                      
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a code behind that registers the script on `Page_Load`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Control control, Type type, string key, string script, bool addScriptTags);
}
```

Control control refers to your UpdatePanel variable

[MSDN: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558)